# Cannot shortcuting fix problem in jdeveloper

Tags: java, ide, jdeveloper

I want use "fix problem" shortcut in JDeveloper IDE like it is in Idea e.g.(Alt+Enter).
Cannot find it googling.

Comment: Why are you convinced it exists?

Comment: Its frustrating then. For instance you write `myMethod(foo);` , it warns by red,and it certainly should be there to create the stub method...Such a swift IDE on compiling and run! Nothing stands near :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which exact JDev version do you use?
If you type fixme(); in a line and this method doesn't exist, you should see a red light bulb in the left side gutter. Click on it and it shows you what to do to fix the problem.

[image: red light bulb]

click on red light bulb

[image: show fixes]

You can try to assign a shortcut key to the 'quick fixes' method and see if it more works like in IDEA.

Comment: installed yesterday first time. Went to `Tools->preferences->its search field w/ Shortcut typed->in Shortcuts section, in search field w/ 'fix' typed-> assigned that to Cntrl+Semicolon` , but  didnt succeed with `Create method` command.  Seems there is only `create test method`  command which is a bit different  to the purpose, also didnt check that `fix` yet.